conditionaly fill the color to Shape path co-ordinates in Vega-lite
I am trying to fill the path co-ordinates diagram based on the value. but unable to make it.
It is possbile in SVG and trying the same in vega-lite.
the SVG based one is below. ref:
[1]: https://codepen.io/thiru_tbl/pen/gOJBozb
But, in vega-lite is it possible like "pictorial fraction chart"?
mt vega lite code is below. let say, my data Value is 49. the color should be filled till 49.
{
 "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
 "data": { "name": "mydata",
"values": [
  {"Pic": "Pic", "Value":49}
]
},

"vconcat": [
{

  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Pic",
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "point"}, 
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "Value",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 100]}
        }

      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "point",
        "shape": "M -3 0 L 15 0 L 3 -73 L 3 -73 L -3 -1 L -3 0",
        "fill": "#fdfd"
        
      },
      "encoding": {"y": {"datum": 0}}
      
      
},
{
      "data": {"name": "mydata"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "Value", "type": "quantitative"}, 
        "x": {}
      
      },
      "layer": [
        
        {"mark": {"type": "rule", "x2":100},
        "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "Value", "type": "quantitative"} 
        }
        }
     ]
    },
    {
      "data": {"name": "mydata"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "Value", "type": "quantitative"}, 
        "x": {}
      
      },
      "layer": [
        
        {"mark": {"type": "text","align": "left",
  "baseline": "middle",
  "dx": 90, "dy":-0, "size":20},
        "encoding": {
                   "text": {"field": "Value", "type": "quantitative","title": "points"}
               }
        }
     ]
    }

  ]
}
]
}


You will probably need to do this is Vega. You can probably either create a clipping group or generate a second SVG dynamically for the fill. Both approaches are shown in this spec: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase/blob/main/Gantt%20Chart/Gantt%202.0%20Spec.json

You could add a solid gradient to your SVG like this:

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "width": 120,
  "height": 330,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "a": "A",
        "b": 10,
        "c": "M -3 0 L 15 0 L 3 -60 L 3 -60 L -3 -1 L -3 0",
        "d": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {"name": "colorGradient", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['b']/100"},
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "update": "{gradient: 'linear', 'x1': 1,      'y1': 1,  'stops': [    {'offset': 0, 'color': 'red'},    {'offset': colorGradient, 'color': 'red'},    {'offset': colorGradient, 'color': 'white'}  ]}"
    }
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "point",
    "fill": {"signal": "test1"},
    "opacity": 1,
    "stroke": "black",
    "strokeOpacity": 1,
    "clip": true,
    "color": "black",
    "size": 120,
    "xOffset": -25,
    "yOffset": 0
  },
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"value": "black"},
    "y": {"field": "d", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"domain": [0, 100]}},
    "shape": {"field": "c", "type": "quantitative", "scale": null}
  }
}

Here is another simple example where I position the svg based on CPU but color it based on RAM. I haven't seen this before so this opens up many possibilities I think.

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 330,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"LOCATION": "HOUSTON", "RAM": 15, "CPU": 70},
      {"LOCATION": "NY", "RAM": 30, "CPU": 20},
      {"LOCATION": "LA", "RAM": 70, "CPU": 60},
      {"LOCATION": "CHICAGO", "RAM": 90, "CPU": 40}
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "svg",
      "value": "M14.5 2.49866C14.5 3.60194 11.366 4.49731 7.5 4.49731C3.634 4.49731 0.5 3.60194 0.5 2.49866M14.5 2.49866C14.5 1.39538 11.366 0.5 7.5 0.5C3.634 0.5 0.5 1.39538 0.5 2.49866M14.5 2.49866V12.4922C14.5 13.5955 11.366 14.4908 7.5 14.4908C3.634 14.4908 0.5 13.5956 0.5 12.4923V2.49866M14.5 7.49536C14.5 8.59864 11.366 9.49414 7.5 9.49414C3.634 9.49414 0.5 8.59864 0.5 7.49536"
    }
  ],
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum.RAM/100", "as": "b_calc"},
    {"calculate": "svg", "as": "svg"},
    {
      "calculate": "{gradient: 'linear', 'x1': 1,'y1': 1,  'stops': [{'offset': 0, 'color': 'silver'},{'offset': datum.b_calc, 'color': 'silver'},{'offset': datum.b_calc, 'color': 'white'}]}",
      "as": "fillGradient"
    }
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "point",
    "fill": {"expr": "datum.fillGradient"},
    "opacity": 1,
    "stroke": "black",
    "strokeOpacity": 1,
    "clip": true,
    "color": "black",
    "size": 60,
    "xOffset": -35,
    "yOffset": 0
  },
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"value": "black"},
    "x": {"field": "LOCATION", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {
      "field": "CPU",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"domain": [0, 100]}
    },
    "shape": {"field": "svg", "scale": null}
  }
}


Thanks lot.. it works fine and able to place any SVG objects... like filling % in the cars...etc

Glad I could help @sen. This was a fun challenge for sure!
